# How to create File from folder in android assets?

Tags: java, android, assets

I want to list all files in folder which is in assets. But `new File("/android_asset/instagram").exists()` always returns false.

```
File instagram = new File("/android_asset/instagram")

for (File lookUpFile : instagram.listFiles()) {
            String filterName = FileUtils.removeExtension(lookUpFile.getName());
            filterName = Strings.capitalizeAndCopy(filterName);
            GPUImageLookupFilter lookupFilter = new GPUImageLookupFilter();
            lookupFilter.setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(lookUpFile.getAbsolutePath()));
            filters.addFilter(filterName, lookupFilter);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to access the file using asset manager. Try to get the list of files and make sure its working.

```
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = assetManager.list("");
```